# Proc means output statement

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with several variables like the one below:

```
Data have(drop=x);
call streaminit(1);
do x = 1 to 20 by 1;
    if x < 11 then group = 'A';
    else group = 'B';
    var1 = rand('normal',0,1);
    var2 = rand('uniform');
    output;
end;
Run;
```

In my analysis I need to get some summary stats using `PROC MEANS` and output the results for each variable into one dataset. I tried doing it with the code below, but it only includes stats from the first variable in the dataset. How can I output the remaining variables into the same dataset?

```
Proc means data=have n sum mean;
By group;
Output out=want(drop=_freq_ _type_) n=n sum=sum mean=mean;
Run;


Output: 
+-------+----+----------+----------+
| group | n  | sum      | mean     |
+-------+----+----------+----------+
| A     | 10 | 4.517081 | 0.451708 |
+-------+----+----------+----------+
| B     | 10 | -0.77369 | -0.07737 |
+-------+----+----------+----------+

Desired output:
+----------+-------+----+----------+----------+
| variable | group | n  | sum      | mean     |
+----------+-------+----+----------+----------+
| var1     | A     | 10 | 4.517081 | 0.451708 |
+----------+-------+----+----------+----------+
| var1     | B     | 10 | -0.77369 | -0.07737 |
+----------+-------+----+----------+----------+
| var2     | A     | 10 | 7.947089 | 0.794709 |
+----------+-------+----+----------+----------+
| var2     | B     | 10 | 5.003049 | 0.500305 |
+----------+-------+----+----------+----------+
```

Comment: The order of the names after the statistics keywords in the OUTPUT statement are matched by position with the names in the VAR statement.  If you only give one name then only the first variable's statistic value is saved.  You can leave the name lists after the `=` empty and add the `/autoname` option and PROC MEANS will calculate distinct names for the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get that output you will need to transpose the data. Either transpose before hand and add the _NAME_ variable to the BY or CLASS statement.

```
data have;
  call streaminit(1);
  do x = 1 to 20 by 1;
    if x < 11 then group = 'A';
    else group = 'B';
    var1 = rand('normal',0,1);
    var2 = rand('uniform');
    output;
  end;
run;
proc transpose data=have out=tall;
  by group x;
run;

proc means data=tall nway n sum mean;
  by group;
  class _name_;
  output out=want(drop=_freq_ _type_) n=n sum=sum mean=mean;
run;
```

Or use `/autoname` and transpose the resulting dataset from one observation per GROUP to multiple observations.

```
proc means data=have(drop=x) nway n sum mean;
  by group;
  output out=wide(drop=_freq_ _type_) n= sum= mean= /autoname;
run;

proc transpose data=wide out=tall;
  by group;
run;
data tall ;
  set tall ;
  stat=scan(_name_,-1,'_');
  _name_=substrn(_name_,1,length(_name_)-length(stat) -1);
  rename _name_=varname;
run;
proc sort data=tall;
  by group varname;
run;

proc transpose data=tall out=want(drop=_name_);
  by group varname ;
  id stat;
  var col1;
run;
proc print data=want;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You requested SAS to name the count `n`, the sum `sum` and the mean `mean`.
It can only do that for one variable.

This is the syntax to ask SAS to use different names for the statistics of each variable:

```
Output out=want(drop=_freq_ _type_) 
    n(var1 var2)=n1 n2 
    sum(var1 var2)=sum1 sum2
    mean(var1 var2)=mean1 mean2;
```